# Where has the QGIS2threejs Icon gone?

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, 3d-map, qgis2threejs

I am trying to create 3D maps. I am using QGis2threejs. I know I can also create a 3D map using 'New 3D Map View', but I want to try QGis2threejs.

However I have two questions.

1. When I install the QGis2threejs plugin. It only allows me to access 'QGis2threejs Eplorer'. Is this the same as 'QGis2threejs' because from looking at tutorials it seems a completely different tool to what I want to be using.
2. where Has my icon for 'QGis2threejs' gone in my tool bar. An icon for 'QGis2threejs Explorer' appear but once again this layout is different to all the tutorials I am following.

I am using QGIS V3.4

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial you're following? Chances are those tutorials were made using QGIS 2 and with all the changes made for QGIS 3, I wouldn't be surprised if the author(s) made changes to the plugin interface since they would have had to update the source code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVZTaA-a9kk. And https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs/Tutorial.html.  You might be right, the first thutorial was made in 2015

Comment: The tool is in the Web - Qgis2threejs Exporter (not Explorer). Don't let it bother if the tool looks a bit different than in the tutorial. Just go on and experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS is a program with fairly frequent updates. It's quite common to find well-regarded tutorials from a previous version of the program, or with an older version of a plugin. In these tutorials, there may be minor cosmetic changes such as altered button icons, different color schemes and different interface layouts. If the changes are mostly cosmetic, the tutorial author won't see any reason to update the tutorial.

Unfortunately, sometimes this may be true even when the changes are substantial. It's one of the downsides of open-source software, compared to expensive software that has a large infrastructure of paid staff to write and update tutorials. In this case, you can either try to find a tutorial from a different source, or try your best to follow the older tutorial.

Fortunately, the official qgis2threejs website has [a tutorial](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs/Tutorial.html) made using QGIS 3 (based on the color of the QGIS logo in the screenshots - yellow in QGIS 2, green in QGIS 3). Here's where to find the plugin button:

> click the plugin icon [image] in the web toolbar to open the Qgis2threejs exporter.